# C++ Array Sorting With Indices

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, indexing, bubble-sort

I need to sort a `float arr[256][16]` array while retaining the original indices of the elements. So, for instance, if the indices of x = [7,12,4] are 0, 1, 2, I would like to sort this array as [4,7,12] and "remember" the indices as 2,0,1. Also, the container must be a standard array, even if its easier to use structures to store the values and indices of each object. So far, I've done it using simple Bubblesort and storing the indices where elements get swapped,but it's giving me incorrect results. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You might sort indexes array according to reference array. `std::ranges::sort(indexes, std::ranges::less{}, [&](int index){ return x[index]; });`.

Comment: what is a "standard array" ? `std::array` ? Even if the container is an array, what prevents you from sorting some structure with values and indices ?

Comment: ... and why use bubble-sort?

Comment: It is a hardware implementation in Vivado HLS, so I need to keep resource consumption to a minimum. That's also why I can't use built-in algorithms. My arrays are defined as float arr[256][16].

Comment: What resoruces? Unless you have very few elements, bubble-sort is likely to consume more CPU cycles/power than most alternatives.

Comment: You're right, bubblesort isn't what I'm going for ultimately but that's where I started. I already have the values calculated and stored in an array, and making copies of them/replacing it with a struct would take up more on-chip memory.

Comment: It's probably easier to simply sort the array first, and then figure out (in the same N log N) where each unsorted element ended up. In your example, x[0]=7 ended up in sorted[1] so index[1]=0. This is just N binary searches, taking values from input and finding them in the sorted output. This also allows hardware parallelization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is, to sort the indices, based on the values in the array. And leave the array as is. And later access the elements through the index array.

So, you compare the real float values, if one is less than the other, but then, exhange the index values in the index array.

This could look like the below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int NumberOfRows = 256;
const int NumberOfColumns = 16;

float arr[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];
unsigned char index[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

int main() {

    // Fill index array (and create test data)
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row)
        for (int col = 0; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {
            index[row][col] = col;
            arr[row][col] = row * NumberOfColumns+ (NumberOfColumns - col-1);
        }

    // Sort all 256 rows. But sort the indices only, not the arr values
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row)
        std::sort(index[row], index[row] + NumberOfColumns, [&](const int i1, const int i2) {return arr[row][i1] < arr[row][i2]; });

    // Show debug output
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        std::cout << "\nRow: " << row << "  -->  ";
        for (int col = 0; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col)
            std::cout << arr[row][index[row][col]] << ' ';
    }
}
```

If you wan to sort both the values and the indices then you could write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int NumberOfRows = 256;
const int NumberOfColumns = 16;

float arr[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];
unsigned char index[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

int main() {

    // Fill index array (and create test data)
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row)
        for (int col = 0; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {
            index[row][col] = col;
            arr[row][col] = row * NumberOfColumns + (NumberOfColumns - col - 1);
        }

    // Sort all 256 rows. 
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        std::sort(index[row], index[row] + NumberOfColumns, [&](const int i1, const int i2) {return arr[row][i1] < arr[row][i2]; });
        std::sort(arr[row], arr[row] + NumberOfColumns);
    }
    // Show debug output
    for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        std::cout << "\nRow: " << row << "  -->  ";
        for (int col = 0; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col)
            std::cout << arr[row][col] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Now you have the arr values sorted and the index values sorted.

Comment: Thanks @Armin Montigny, your code gives me the following error.

`error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(uint [1024], uint*, grouperPE(PCStream&, PCStream&, indexStream&, PCStream&)::<lambda(int, int)>)’
note: candidates are:
gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_algo.h:5394:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter)
note: template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
make: *** [obj/grouperPE.o] Error 1`